# I can't get formula to work in a column that is referencing another cell that happens to be using the importxml command

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, indexing, match

Am I allowed to share the link to my google sheets to have someone look at it?
I have column G that is not calculating correctly and I can't understand why.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XGDcgIYhW4_cq065MM7i135AyJha8JcMGejATuoVT7Q/edit?usp=sharing

My only guess is it doesn't like to refer to a cell that is pulling in data from and import command. The formula calculates fine in excel but not in sheets, any suggestion?

Formula is:

```
=IF(B17="Purchase",index($E4:$E12,match(C17,$B$4:$B$12))*D17,"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(B17="Purchase", INDEX($E4:$E12, MATCH(C17, $B$4:$B$12, 0))*D17, )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Man I love the internet. Can you explain why sheets needs this and not excel, what is that doing?

Comment: @jsunsnow sure. 0 as 3rd MATCH argument tells to perform "exact match" while nothing or 1 would perform "approximate match"